# Render template after fetching data from mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, templates, handlebars.js, each

```
app.get('/clients', (req, res) => {
    var clientArray;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Clients', (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to Connect');
        }
        console.log('Connected to Mongodb server');
        db.collection('Clients').find().toArray().then((docs) => {
            clientArray = JSON.stringify(docs, undefined, 2);
            // clientArray = docs;
            console.log(clientArray);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("ERROR")
        });
        db.close();
    });
    res.render('clients.hbs', {
        infoArray: clientArray,
        name: 'Harshit'
    });
});
```

Here the res.render function is being called before getting the required data from the mongodb database. I want to pass the data fetched as an array to the handlebars template.

```
{{#each infoArray}}
        <h1>{{this.name}}</h1>
        {{this.region}}
        {{/each}}
```

Here I am trying to go through the array rendered and display the data.Any Help is appreciated.
Structure of array

```
[{
        "name": "harshit",
        "region": "delhi"
    },
    {
        "name": "mendax",
        "region": "ecuador"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Render has to be in callback function :

```
app.get('/clients', (req, res) => {
var clientArray;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Clients', (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to Connect');
    }
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb server');
    db.collection('Clients').find().toArray().then((docs) => {
        clientArray = JSON.stringify(docs, undefined, 2);
        // clientArray = docs;
        console.log(clientArray);
         db.close();

        res.render('clients.hbs', {
          infoArray: clientArray,
          name: 'Harshit'
        });

    }, (err) => {
        console.log("ERROR")
         db.close();
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

This is happening becuse `MongoClient.connect(..` is asynchronous. So you `res.render` executes before that.

What you need is, just move your `res.render` inside that block

```
app.get('/clients', (req, res) => {
    var clientArray;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Clients', (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to Connect');
        }
        console.log('Connected to Mongodb server');
        db.collection('Clients').find().toArray().then((docs) => {
            clientArray = JSON.stringify(docs, undefined, 2);
            // clientArray = docs;
            res.render('clients.hbs', {
                infoArray: clientArray,
                name: 'Harshit'
            });
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("ERROR")
        });
        db.close();
    });

});
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks.